# How to configure Azure AD permissions to access Microsoft Graph from the WebJob console app?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-webjobs

I cannot access Microsoft Graph inside of WebJob (basically console app). I'm getting "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" error when I try to fetch users from AD.

I'm building a scheduled webjob which is supposed to sync user details from time to time. For that purpose I'm connecting to graph, fetching users.
The same code is working in case if I authenticate on behalf of user, using real user token, but it requires user to open web application and click the button.

I have app id and secret to connect but it was generated in the past for web application itself. Is it supposed to be working in my scenario or I should generate a separate Id/secret and configure it in a different way.

Here is some code:

```
var pages = activeDirectoryClient.Users.Where(adItem => adItem.Mail == o.Email).ExecuteAsync().Result;


var activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await GetTokenAsync(authContext, azureAdParameters.UserObjectId, azureAdParameters.HostUrl));
```

ActiveDirectoryClient is used to fetch users data, but it comes from 
Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient
Does it need Microsoft Graph API permissions or Azure AD Graph API permissions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebJob is is not a public client - it is a confidential client. There is no user present to authenticate when it needs to get tokens & it knows how to protect secrets (that's the definition of confidential client). It needs to authenticate by itself. You need to give it the appropriate **Application** Permissions (User.Read.All is a **delegated** permission - it won't work), have them consented to if needed by an administrator and use the AcquireToken method which uses ClientCredentials (app id and symmetric key or, better an X509 cert).

Comment: Sounds reasonable and clear. Thanks, will try that. Also was going to ask about admin consent option - it is technically just a tickbox ot sign a permission as trusted like or it requires additional call to API as I have seen in native calls implementation - first http call to confirm the consent and second to get the token?
For time being - I'm getting the token using context.AcquireTokenAsync(GraphResourceId, clientCredentials). It gets it correctly, just fails when I try to fetch users from AD with aforementioned exception which looks like permission issue which you mentioned.

Comment: An admin can grant consent through the Azure portal.Alternatively, this article explains how to get consent to an API using a signin link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/trusted-application-api/docs/tenantadminconsent (replace client and reply uri with your data). You need an admin to use that link to sign in and grant consent.

Comment: Thanks. Everything (almost) worked. I had to change the client, it was by mistake Azure AD Graph Client instead of MS Graph Service Client. So with granted permissions it connects and fetches the user. With only one issue, almost all information is empty, but should contains e.g. address .. now I have only contact phone number and email, name surname.. Can it be connected to any other permission or there is different data while fetching thru MS Graph and Azure AD Graph? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your old web app registration lacks needed application permissions. So my advice would be:

1. Register a new application in Azure AD;
2. Give it Microsoft Graph API Permissions (Application): User.Read.All and Directory.Read.All;
3. Generate a new client secret for the new app registration;
4. Re-configure your WebJob to use the new application client id and secret.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Everything (almost) worked. I had to change the client, it was by mistake Azure AD Graph Client instead of MS Graph Service Client. So with granted permissions it connects and fetches the user. With only one issue, almost all information is empty, but should contains e.g. address .. now I have only contact phone number and email, name surname.. Can it be connected to any other permission or there is different data while fetching thru MS Graph and Azure AD Graph? 
Thanks